# HID.node is not a valid win32 application

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-builder

I am trying to create a POS software using Electron (ERB), and I got to the part where I need to connect my barcode scanner so I thought `node-hid` was the best package to use. It worked fine on the Linux PC where I am building it, so I tried to package and install it to my Windows laptop (x64), other functionalities worked fine but I was getting an error saying `\\?\C:\Users\zamarah\AppData\Local\Programs\XGen\resources\app.asar.unpacked\node_modules\node-hid\build\Release\HID.node is not a valid Win32 application.`.

**`Questions`**

- How can I make `node-hid` work on ERB when I run it on my Windows device?
- Are there any other alternative ways I can try?

**`Info`**

- Node Version: `18.17.0`
- Electron Version: `^25.0.1`

**`Process`**

```
> cd release/app && npm install node-hid --build-from-source
> ./node_modules/.bin/electron-rebuild
> cd ../../ && npx cross-env DEBUG_PROD=true npm run package -- --win
```

**`Packaging output`**

```
  • electron-builder  version=24.6.3 os=5.15.0-53-generic
  • loaded configuration  file=package.json ("build" field)
  • writing effective config  file=release/build/builder-effective-config.yaml
  • rebuilding native dependencies  dependencies=bcrypt@5.1.1, msgpackr-extract@3.0.2, node-hid@3.0.0, sqlite3@5.1.6 platform=win32 arch=x64
  • packaging       platform=win32 arch=x64 electron=25.6.0 appOutDir=release/build/win-unpacked
  • building        target=nsis file=release/build/XGen Setup 4.6.0.exe archs=x64 oneClick=true perMachine=false
  • building block map  blockMapFile=release/build/XGen Setup 4.6.0.exe.blockmap
```